# Is Lync CWE is compatible with Skype for Business

Tags: skype, lync, skype-for-business, ucma

I need to integrate Lync Conversation Window Extension(CWE) with Skype for business(s4b) for some project requirement. Is CWE compatible with s4b? if yes how feasible it is to implement it.
On official documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/how-to-create-a-conversation-window-extension-application-in-lync-sdk of for Lync CWE, there were three prerequisites for this development - 
1. Microsoft Lync 2013 must be installed and running on the development computer.
2. You must have sign-in credentials for Microsoft Lync Server 2013.
3. Microsoft Lync 2013 SDK must be installed on the development computer.

So that is why I have doubt whether it is compatible with s4b or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, CWEs still work with Skype for Business 2015 and 2019. However, using them comes with a slight risk as the client SDK is [out of mainstream support](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2018/04/microsoft-lync-2013-software-development-kit-moving-from-mainstream-support-to-extended-support-april-20-my-thoughts/)

Comment: I have to implement it at organisational level. So how difficult it can be, what possible hurdles/bottlenecks I will face while implementing? I don't want to give in time and efforts if it is not worth.

Comment: It depends on your exact requirements, but i'd say the main thing to watch out for is the dependency on Silverlight - you'd need to use Visual Studio 2015 as Silverlight is not supported in more recent versions https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/8db2843d-ebb2-4b07-bef1-c0994d34b2ca/will-silverlight-work-with-visual-studio-2017?forum=silverlightgen

Comment: You'd also need to make sure Silverlight is available on each client machine, and ensure you have a mechanism for rolling out reg settings to each client. It's probably best to reduce your dependency on Silverlight (although you can't get rid of it completely). To do this, you could build the majority of your application in HTML/Javascript, and just have Silverlight handle the SfB sign-in, methods and events you need. You could then bridge the two worlds using Javascript.

Comment: Okay! I am new to CWE development. Can you share a good tutorial/documentation/example code which can help me to understand and develop. I find Microsoft documentation bit confusing.

Comment: There really isn't much information out there unfortunately in the way of walkthroughs. I'd suggest either working through the Microsoft document you linked and asking specific questions as and when you hit blockers, or look for external assistance in the way of training and/or consultancy. - Disclaimer: my company offers this, see my bio for details

Comment: Is it possible to Invoke CWE from code to open on client machine automatically using UCMA 5.0 SDK. If yes how... I didn't get anything relevant on internet. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Absolutely, this is a core scenario for UCMA and CWE apps. You need to look at Contextual Conversations - try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/contextual-lync-conversations and https://blogs.claritycon.com/establishing-a-context-channel-between-a-ucma-3-0-application-and-a-silverlight-application-in-the-a7a1e1f5de99 for example